# count objects in loop (show number)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, count

I want display wordpress loop but I want only show count of items in the loop filtered by a custom field value. I don't want to show the title or the content, only the count. This is what I have:

```
<?php query_posts('meta_key=city&meta_value=Seelbach');  ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $count++; //increment the variable by 1 each time the loop executes ?>

            <div>
                <?php if ($count==1) {
                    echo "1";
                }
                elseif ($count==2) {
                    echo "2";
                }
                elseif ($count==3) {
                    echo "3";
                }
                elseif ($count==4) {
                    echo "4";
                } ?>
            </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

but the output is "1 2" - he shows each item and gives it a number but i only want to show the count of ALL (in this case 2 ... ) items that fit to my meta_value. that means i only want to show the "2".

Comment: you want to show only the last element or just the no of elements ?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve basically? make it clear.

Comment: just move your strange ifs outside while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a loop to get the total number, simply use `count` on the posts array returned by `get_posts`:

```
echo count(get_posts(array('meta_key' => 'city', 'meta_value' => 'Seelbach')));
```

Edit as per comment:

```
$count = count(get_posts(array('meta_key' => 'city', 'meta_value' => 'Seelbach')));

if($count){
    //your link code here
}
```

Comment: any idea how to link to an archive page filtered by a meta_value?

Comment: any idea how to implement an "if" query to this? i don't want to wrap it with a "a href" when there is no meta value ...

Answer (score 1):

if you want the total count you can get it like this

```
<?php query_posts('meta_key=city&meta_value=Seelbach');  ?>
            <?php $count = 0; ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php $count++; //increment the variable by 1 each time the loop executes ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
           <?php echo "Count".$count; ?>
```

Comment: this works! any idea how to show count numbers of posts with other "meta_value"? there are more cities than "Seelbach", e.g. "Berlin", Hamburg" etc. and i want to show how many posts i have with each meta_value ...

Comment: @herrfischer  <?php wp_count_posts( $type, $perm ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the total number of posts inside the loop, do something like this (result will always be 2):

```
<?php $posts = query_posts('meta_key=city&meta_value=Seelbach');  ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php
            <div>
                <?php echo count($posts); ?>
            </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

If you need the posts count only once, place the div outside the loop

```
<?php $posts = query_posts('meta_key=city&meta_value=Seelbach');  ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

           <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
               <?php
               // do something with post data
               ?>
           <?php endwhile; ?> 
           <div>
               <?php echo count($posts); ?>
           </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```